# A subset which is closed in $\Bbb Q$ but not closed in $\Bbb R$

Tags: general-topology

Let $A = \{x \in \Bbb Q : 2<x^2<4\}$ Prove that $A$ is closed in $\Bbb Q$ but not closed in $\Bbb R$ Also what is a difference between closed in $\Bbb Q$ and closed in $\Bbb R$.

Edit :  $B = \{x \in \Bbb Q : 2\leq x^2\leq 4\}$ . Is $B$ a bounded subset of$\Bbb Q$  ?

I know that $A$ is closed iff its complement is open.

Comment: Compute the closure of the set in $\mathbb R$. Intersect it with $\mathbb Q$. See what happens.

Comment: $A$ is not closed in $\Bbb Q$. Did you mean $2<x^2\le 4$?

Comment: Yeah, I was going to say what @TonyK said. It is true if you use $3$ or $5$ instead of $4,$ too.

Answer (score 1):

A subset "closed" in $\mathbb{Q}$ is nothing but saying the set is closed with respect to the subspace topology of $\mathbb{Q}$, i.e., of the form $\widetilde{A}\cap \mathbb{Q}$, where $\widetilde{A}$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Note the the set $A$ you have considered is nothing but $([\sqrt{2},2]\cup [-2,-\sqrt{2}])\cap \mathbb{Q}.$ Since $[\sqrt{2},2]\cup [-2,-\sqrt{2}]$ is a closed set $\mathbb{R}$, the set $A$ is closed in $\mathbb{Q}$. However, it is not closed in $\mathbb{R}$, as every irrational is a limit of some sequence of rationals.

Comment: This is wrong, as the question is written: $[\sqrt 2,2]$ should be $(\sqrt 2,2)$. Which means that $A$ is _not_ closed in $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Except $2\notin A$ and $2\in \overline{A}.$

Comment: Thankyou@TonyK for your comment. However, I believe that the inequality $<4$ will not be strict, as it will ensure that the mentioned set is not closed. I have tried to edit but failed. The inequality in the left won't create any problem, as it is itself an irrational.

Comment: I agree with you@ThomasAndrews. I feel that the question has a typo, I have written the proof assuming the correct one.

Comment: Can we assume $A$ is closed in $\mathbb{Q}$ by knowing that it is closed in $\mathbb{A}$? We would be able to come to this conclusion if $\mathbb{Q}$ were closed in $\mathbb{R}$, which it is not.

Comment: Thankyou@XxkiNGDRAgONL0rDxX420 for your comment. "$A$ is closed in $\mathbb{Q}$ by knowing that it is closed in $\mathbb{R}$" is NOT true, and I have never mentioned that. What I have said is that every closed(open) set in a subspace topology (say subspace topology of $\mathbb{Q}$ with respect to $\mathbb{R}$) is obtained by intersecting a closed (open) set of the mother space ($\mathbb{R}$) with $\mathbb{Q}$ itself.